# Put php in a js page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I would like to put a jQuery function which contain php in my main.js page. I have this code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var r = parseInt('<?php the_field('red'); ?>'); 
    var g = parseInt('<?php the_field('green'); ?>'); 
    var b = parseInt('<?php the_field('blue'); ?>');


    $("body").css('background-color', 'rgb(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ')');

        var alpha = Math.min($(this).scrollTop() / 2000, 1);
        var r = Math.round((230-parseInt('<?php the_field('red'); ?>')) * alpha + parseInt('<?php the_field('red'); ?>')); 
        /* red : (fin - début + début) */
        var g = Math.round((230-parseInt('<?php the_field('green'); ?>')) * alpha + parseInt('<?php the_field('green'); ?>')); 
        /* red : (fin - début + début) */
        var b = Math.round((230-parseInt('<?php the_field('blue'); ?>')) * alpha + parseInt('<?php the_field('blue'); ?>')); 

   $(document).scroll(function() {
        /* red : (fin - début + début) */
        $("body").css('background-color', 'rgb(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ')');
    });

</script>
```

Si I did that :

In my php code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _COLORS_ = {
        r: parseInt('<?php the_field('red'); ?>'), 
        g: parseInt('<?php the_field('green'); ?>'),
        b: parseInt('<?php the_field('blue'); ?>')
  };
</script>
```

In my main.js :

```
    $("body").css('background-color', 'rgb(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ')');

        var alpha = Math.min($(this).scrollTop() / 2000, 1);
        var r = Math.round((230-r) * alpha + r); 
        var g = Math.round((230-g) * alpha + g); 
        var b = Math.round((230-b) * alpha + b); 

   $(document).scroll(function() {

        $("body").css('background-color', 'rgb(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ')');
    });
```

But it doesn't work, maybe I made a error or forgot something.

Comment: Check the console for any errors.

Comment: Your `Math.round()` calls are missing closing parentheses

Comment: It was a keyboard error... I edited the code.

Answer (score 1):

You assign the value into a JS object. You can use the value like :

```
_COLORS_.r
_COLORS_.g
_COLORS_.b
```

So your code looks like :

```
$("body").css('background-color', 'rgb(' + _COLORS_.r + ',' + _COLORS_.g + ',' + _COLORS_.b + ')');

var alpha = Math.min($(this).scrollTop() / 2000, 1);
var r = Math.round((230 - _COLORS_.r) * alpha + _COLORS_.r);
var g = Math.round((230 - _COLORS_.g) * alpha + _COLORS_.g);
var b = Math.round((230 - _COLORS_.b) * alpha + _COLORS_.b);

$(document).scroll(function() {

  $("body").css('background-color', 'rgb(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ')');
});
```